# Remove-PSDrive doesn't remove Mapped Drives

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-5.0

I am having trouble deleting a specific drive for a user in my script.
I cannot use **NET USE** as it is removed by security guys in my place.
**Remove-PSDrive -Name X** only removes it for the PS shell not the user's explorer.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are after is the [WScript.Network](https://ss64.com/vb/removenetworkdrive.html) Com Object.

```
# Create new object
$NetDrive = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
# Remove the network drive (Drive Letter, Force Removal, Remove Mapping)
$NetDrive.RemoveNetworkDrive('X:',$True,$True)
```

Without doing `$True` twice, it will only disconnect the mapped drive.

You can map it by doing the below.

```
# Add the network drive (Drive Letter, Path, Persistent, Username, Password)
$NetDrive.MapNetworkDrive($drive, $path, "true", $user, $pwd)
```

Comment: Sir, you are a life saver! Thank you!
How do I map the drive using the same method?